# ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start not available when Rails environment is production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Interesting.  `ObjectSpace` doesn't include the `trace_object_allocations_start` method (and related methods) when RAILS_ENV is production. Is there a way to change this?

```
[dhaskin@six plume (master *$%=)]$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
[1] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start
=> nil
[2] pry(main)>
[dhaskin@six plume (master *$%=)]$ RAILS_ENV=production rails c
W, [2016-06-05T09:46:20.872062 #12364]  WARN -- : ** [Honeybadger] Unable to start Honeybadger -- api_key is missing or invalid. level=2 pid=12364
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
2.3.1 :001 > ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start
NoMethodError: undefined method `trace_object_allocations_start' for ObjectSpace:Module
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/dhaskin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@plume/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/dhaskin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@plume/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/dhaskin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@plume/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/dhaskin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@plume/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/dhaskin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@plume/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.3.1 :002 >
```

(Note this happens when running the server as well, this is just an easy way to demonstrate.)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out these `ObjectSpace` extensions need to be required, so if I add

```
require 'objspace'
```

it works as expected in production.  My best guess is that some gem being loaded in `development` was doing this `require` for me, which is why I didn't have to explicitly require it.